# How does $(a,b)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

Well I can't think how the open set $(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ can be formed from this basis.

Answer (score 6):

The set
$$A=\bigcup_{\begin{align}a,b\in&\Bbb Q\\\sqrt 2<a<&b<\sqrt 3\end{align}} (a,b)$$
is obviously a subset of $(\sqrt2,\sqrt 3)$ as each used $(a,b)$ is.
On the other hand, if $x\in\Bbb R$ with $\sqrt 2<x<\sqrt 3$, we can find rational numbers $a,b$ with $\sqrt2<a<x<b<\sqrt 3$ (why?) and hence $x\in (a,b)\subseteq A$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the decimeal representation of $\sqrt{2}$:
$$\sqrt{2} = 1.414213562373 \dots$$
Let's make a rational sequence $a_n$ converging to $\sqrt{2}$, with $a_n \geq \sqrt{2}$ for all $n$.  Take $a_1 = 1.5$, $a_2 = 1.42$, $a_3 = 1.415$, $a_4 = 1.4143$, etc: truncate the decimal representation of $\sqrt{2}$ and round it **up**. Clearly, $a_n \to \sqrt{2}$.

Similarly, you make a rational sequence $b_n$ converging to $\sqrt{3}$, with $b_n \leq \sqrt{3}$ for all $n$, by truncating and rounding **down**.

You then have a sequence of intervals $(a_n,b_n) \subseteq (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ with $a_n \to \sqrt{2}$ and $b_n \to \sqrt{3}$. Hence
$$(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}) = \bigcup_n \;(a_n,b_n).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_n$ be a decreasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt2 = 1.41421356\ldots$, for instance $1.5, 1.42, 1.415, 1.4143,\ldots$. Let $b_n$ be an increasing sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt3=1.7320508\ldots$, for instance $1.7, 1.73, 1.732,\ldots$. Then we have that
$$
(\sqrt 2, \sqrt3) = \bigcup_{n\in \Bbb N}(a_n, b_n)
$$
so $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt3)$ is a union of basis elements and therefore open.